# Files in .gitignore are getting over-written in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I want connection_util.py file to be ignored by Jenkins when deploying code in AWS lambda from bitbucket.
Using below -

```
/env
/.vscode
/ve
/.idea
/helper/connection_util.py
```

But when executing the build, it over-writes the file. 
However, it is working fine in the local environment.

Is there something else I need to do to gitignore a file in Jenkins.

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by working in local environment? Also is the file ready in repo and you added file to ignore in .gitignore later?

Comment: @slashpai Yes, file is ready in repo ad I added file in .gitignore later. With local environment I mean if I sync it in my system

Comment: Adding a file in .gitignore after its been already committing won't ignore it. You would require to remove it using git reset or git rm

Comment: I have answered below which might help you. If it does pls accept as answer :)

Comment: These seem to be specified as absolute paths, and probably won't match anything in the Jenkins workspace directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your connection_util.py was already been tracked and commited before adding in .gitignore, it won't ignore it. You would require to remove it from index to stop tracking

```
git rm --cached <file need to remove>
```

So that would be issue in your case since Jenkins is still able to see the file in repo